# Angular Material Design Layout custom sizes

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

How to add custom flex attributes for different sizes of the screen?
Referring to the spec here : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/layout/options

For example, the flex attribute 
`flex-gt-lg`    Sets flex on devices greater than 1200px wide. I want to add one more attribute say something like `flex-gt-lgx` which sets flex on devices greater than 1600px wide, for which angular material does not provide support. How will do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

codeMan,

You will have to change the CSS in a way or another.

**Complex way**

Go to their css resources an alter it to fit your needs

**Easier way**

Create your own CSS changes overwriting theirs with `!important`

```
@media screen and (min-width:1200px) {     
.yourclass { 
      width:100% !important; 
      background:#ccc !important; 
      float:none !important;     }  
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks bobleujr! I went with creating my own css write a media query to select a flex-gt-lgx attribute of a span tag and used, css flex property.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a media query as follows :

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1601px) {
    [flex-gt-lgx="25"] {
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
        flex: 0 0 25%;
    }
}
```

and used the following  span tag

```
<span flex-md="10" flex-sm="5" flex-lg="15" flex-gt-lg="20" flex-gt-lgx="25" ></span>
```

and it worked as expected!!

**Note:** Downside of doing this is that `flex-gt-lgx` should be always set to `25` value.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@codeMan answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32649092/5583283) with media query ...

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1601px) {
    [flex-gt-lgx="25"] {
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 25%;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
        flex: 0 0 25%;
    }
}
```

#### Custom Angular directive

You could write a custom directive for `flex-gt-lgx` that would generate the CSS to be apply in the `style` attribute with the desired flex value passed from the directive parameter.

That way you wouldn't be limited to the hardcoded CSS values.

#### Mimic the Angular Material CSS

You could make the same thing as Angular Material and create **all** the CSS for possible flex values as stated in their documentation and than use the `flex-gt-lgx` attribute on the desired HTML tag just like any other flex directive.

> Currently, the flex directive value is restricted to multiples of five, 33 or 66.
>
> For example: flex="5", flex="20", flex="33", flex="50", flex="66", flex="75", ... flex="100".

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/children